# Idiomatic Error?

Tags: idioms

I would like to know if the usage of "to slip through your hands" is a major idiomatic error. Should it be "slip through your fingers"?

As in:

> It may sometimes seem an opportunity slipped through your hands.

Comment: Not entirely unknown. *Fingers* is more usual. But it would be helpful to know more of the context.

Comment: @WS2 I am trying to say, for example, "You let the opportunity slip through your hands by not signing the contract."

Comment: Yes. That would be idiomatic. More usual to say *fingers*, but *hands* is fine.

Comment: [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slipped+through+his+hands%2Cslipped+through+his+fingers%2Cslipped+through+my+hands%2Cslipped+through+my+fingers&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslipped%20through%20his%20hands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslipped%20through%20his%20fingers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslipped%20through%20my%20hands%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslipped%20through%20my%20fingers%3B%2Cc0) supports the (apparently popular) notion that *fingers* is more common but *hands* is acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not as common as *slip through your fingers*, some things can slip through your hands - like a rope or a fish - rather than through your fingers, like sand.

Comment: How about intangible things like opportunity? I know there are many examples for the usage of "an opportunity slipping through someone's fingers" but can "hands" be used instead of "fingers" here?

Comment: Yes, that's the usage the OP used in his example. You would really only use an idiom in the case of an intangible.  If it were a tangible, you would just say it literally, "*the football slipped through my hands*".

Comment: So just trying to confirm: The usage OP used in his example is grammatically correct. Right?

Comment: Yes, the grammar is fine.